# Need direction about Controller, Views, Routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 models.

Customer and Store Models.
A Customer can have many Stores.

I created basic/scaffolding controllers and views for both.

So Customer Controller has Index, Create, Edit, Delete actions.

In my index view for Customer, I want to have a link to "Stores" for each customer which will take to "Store" Index page, only that it will show a list for that client...

Now usually we have URL patterns such as

```
          /Customer/Create
          /Customer/Details/Id
          /Customer/Edit/Id
```

As mentioned, I want a Stores link beside Edit/Delete/Details which will work something like,

```
          /Customer/1/Store/Index
          /Customer/1/Store/Create
          /Customer/1/Store/Edit/1
```

My URL construction maybe wrong but that is my idea. How does one achieve this kind of behavior. Do I create a Store Function within the Customer Controller? I am confused on then how will I acheive /Customer/1/Store/Edit/1 this kind of behavior...

I am looking for reading material because I am unsure what to search for..Also, the URL pattern is not what I am looking for...I am looking for an easy way to implement this. Dont know if that makes sense..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routing in asp.net mvc is quite flexible.  With the template projects (and many samples) you get this route:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Giving you a url like `/Customer/Edit/1` for controller "Customer", Action "Edit", id "1".

But you don't have to follow that pattern. So you can do something like:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Store",
        url: "Customer/{customerId}/Store/{action}/{storeId}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Store", action = "Index", storeId = UrlParameter.Optional, customerId = 0 }
        );
```

And then create an action method in your `Store` controller like:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int customerId, int storeId) { ... }
```

Letting you use the route `/Customer/1/Store/Edit/3`

Just remember that the *first* route that can possibly match will match, even if there is a better match defined later.

Comment: OK. That pointer was really useful. I was not thinking like that.... will read up on this now. Thank you !